# Laravel HTTP Test - Make sure JSON response has specific value in array

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a Laravel 8 app I am writing a test for. Here is what my data looks like:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Cumque ex quos.",
            "createdAt": "2020-12-29T17:15:32.000000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-12-29T17:15:32.000000Z",
            "startAt": "2021-01-18 17:15:32",
            "endAt": "2021-01-18 17:15:32",
            "startedAt": null,
            "status": "Running",
            "range": {
                "type": "percentage",
                "max": 0,
                "min": 0
            },
        },
        {
            "name": "Cumque ex quos 2.",
            "createdAt": "2020-12-29T17:15:32.000000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-12-29T17:15:32.000000Z",
            "startAt": "2021-01-18 17:15:32",
            "endAt": "2021-01-18 17:15:32",
            "startedAt": null,
            "status": "Running",
            "range": {
                "type": "percentage",
                "max": 20,
                "min": 100
            },
        },
    ],
    "other_keys" [ ... ];
}
```

I want to test that every value of `status` in the response is equal to the value `Running`. Here's what my test looks like:

```php
/** @test */
public function should_only_return_data_that_are_running()
{
    $response = $this->getJson('/api/v2/data');

    $response->assertJsonPath('data.*.status', 'Running');
}
```

This fails with the following:

```
Failed asserting that Array &0 (
    0 => 'Running'
    1 => 'Running'
) is identical to 'Running'.
```

I am obviously testing this incorrectly. What's the best way to test all of the objects returned in the `data` array and ensure that the `status` value is equal to `Running`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're asserting a path that includes a wildcard, you will be getting the value of each matching item (this function uses [the `data_get()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-data-get) in the background.) You'll need to build a structure with the same number of elements. Something like this maybe:

```php
public function should_only_return_data_that_are_running()
{
    $response = $this->getJson('/api/v2/data');
    $test = array_fill(0, count($response->data), 'Running');
    $response->assertJsonPath('data.*.status', $test);
}
```